# How to solve this SQL query (header and detail)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a SQL query question related to header and detail tables. I have a header table where I am storing location & department & week_start_date. I have a detail table where I am storing employee_id & job_code & work_date & hours.

I want to find those employees who are in different headers with same week_start_date but different location and/or department.

Here is the explanation:

---

I have a **header** table:

```
CREATE TABLE header (
    header_id bigint not null PRIMARY KEY,
    location_code int not null,
    department_code int not null,
    week_start_date datetime not null )
```

I have a **detail** table:

```
CREATE TABLE detail (
    detail_id bigint not null PRIMARY KEY,
    header_id bigint not null FOREIGN KEY header(header_id),
    employee_id int not null,
    job_code int not null,
    work_date datetime not null,
    hours decimal(8,2) not null )
```

**header** table has the unique key as location_code + department_code + week_start_date.

For example this is the data in **header** table:

> header_id=11, location_code=22, department_code=33,
>   week_start_date='2016-02-08'
>
> header_id=12, location_code=22, department_code=39,
>   week_start_date='2016-02-08'
>
> header_id=13, location_code=22, department_code=33,
>   week_start_date='2016-02-15'
>
> header_id=14, location_code=21, department_code=33,
>   week_start_date='2016-02-08'

Each row in **header** table can have multiple rows in **detail** table.

**detail** table has the unique key as header_id + employee_id + job_code + work_date.

For example this is the data in **detail** table for 1000598 employee_id:

> detail_id=101, header_id=11, employee_id=1000598, job_code=77,
>   work_date='2016-02-08', hours=5.00
>
> detail_id=102, header_id=11, employee_id=1000598, job_code=77,
>   work_date='2016-02-09', hours=4.00
>
> detail_id=109, header_id=12, employee_id=1000598, job_code=79,
>   work_date='2016-02-11', hours=4.50

For example this is the data in **detail** table for 1000599 employee_id:

> detail_id=121, header_id=11, employee_id=1000599, job_code=78,
>   work_date='2016-02-10', hours=8.00
>
> detail_id=122, header_id=14, employee_id=1000599, job_code=75,
>   work_date='2016-02-12', hours=3.00

For example this is the data in **detail** table for 1000600 employee_id:

> detail_id=131, header_id=11, employee_id=1000600, job_code=72,
>   work_date='2016-02-11', hours=7.00
>
> detail_id=132, header_id=13, employee_id=1000600, job_code=75,
>   work_date='2016-02-17', hours=3.00

The SQL query should return 1000598 employee_id as 1000598 has data for both department_code=33 and department_code=39 for the same week_start_date='2016-02-08'.

The SQL query should return 1000599 employee_id as 1000599 has data for both location_code=22 and location_code=21 for the same week_start_date='2016-02-08'.

The SQL query should not return 1000600 employee_id.

---

This is the start I have come up with:

```
select 
   h.employee_id, 
   d.week_start_date
from 
   header h (nolock) 
      inner join detail d (nolock) 
         on h.header_id = d.header_id 
group by 
   h.employee_id, 
   d.week_start_date
order by 
   1, 
   2
```

Not much.

Comment: School assignment? What you've tried so far?

Comment: LOL not really. This is at job. I have tried GROUP BY but issue is I need distinct on employee_id and where to put the logic for location and/or department check

Comment: Please post your attempt with GROUP BY so that we can debug it.

Comment: posted; not much really

Comment: You say you want dates for '2016-02-08', so why not just add a where clause for that?

Comment: I dont want only dates for '2016-02-08' that was just for example purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to find those employees who are in different headers with same
>   week_start_date but different location and/or department.

The query below will return all `(employee_id, week_start_date)` pairs that have more than 1 `location_code` or `department_code`

```
select d.employee_id, h.week_start_date
from detail d
join header h on h.header_id = d.header_id
group by d.employee_id, h.week_start_date -- employees with same week_start_date
having (
  count(distinct h.location_code) > 1 -- have more than 1 location
  or count(distinct h.department_code) > 1 -- or more than 1 department
)
```

Comment: From what I can see - the question is for a specific date (2016-02-08), so I think you just need to add a where clause for the date, then you can remove your having

Comment: Okay - OP clarified.

Comment: Awesome answer. I did not know that I can use `distinct` with `count` in `having` clause. One question though: Is not `and count(distinct d.header_id) > 1` unnecessary when you are already doing the count on distinct location_code and department_code?

Comment: @srh you're right! if there's more than 1 location or department, then there must be more than 1 header since those fields are defined in the header table

Comment: Thanks @FuzzyTree. I was thinking to go on and write a procedure with loop to solve this issue. This helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
select dtl.* from 
(select * from detail d1 where EXISTS(select count(header_id) from detail d2 where d1.employee_id=d2.employee_id having count(header_id)>1)) 
inner join 
header hd 
on hd.header_id=dtl.header_id 
group by dtl.employee_id, hd.week_start_date 
having count(*)>1
```